# how to update row in Android within cursor.moveToFirst() in android

Tags: android

I would like to update query while i retrieve the data row by row .I want to update data by using following command.

```
db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
db.execSQL("update ActivityObjectList set DownLoad_Status='1' where imageaudioPath ='" + imageName + "'");
```

I'm using above two lines in service in background.

```
public void Loaddata()
    {

            db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from ActivityObjectList", null);

            if (cursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                do {
                    imageName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("imageaudioPath"));
                    str_DownLoadUrl = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("DownLoad_Status"));
                    str_ActiveImageStatus = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ActiveStatus"));
                    if(str_ActiveImageStatus.equals("1"))
                    {
                        if( str_DownLoadUrl.equals("0") )
                        {
                            if(imageName.endsWith(mp3_Pattern))
                            {
                                String fileUrl = namespace + "/DownloadFile/FilePathMobile/ATTACHMENT/FileName/"+imageName;
                                newFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + File.separator + "classnkk_audio");
                                download_PngFileImgLoader(fileUrl, newFolder , imageName);
                                db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                                db.execSQL("update ActivityObjectList set DownLoad_Status='1' where imageaudioPath ='" + imageName + "'");

                            }

                        }

                        if( str_DownLoadUrl.equals("0") )
                        {
                            if(imageName.endsWith(png_Pattern) || imageName.endsWith(jpg_pattern) || imageName.endsWith(bmp_pattern) || imageName.endsWith(gif_pattern) || imageName.endsWith(jpeg_pattern))
                            {
                                String fileUrl = namespace + "/DownloadFile/FilePathMobile/ATTACHMENT/FileName/"+imageName;
                                newFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + File.separator + "classnkk_images");
                                download_PngFileImgLoader(fileUrl, newFolder, imageName);
                                db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                                db.execSQL("update ActivityObjectList set DownLoad_Status='1' where imageaudioPath ='" + imageName + "'");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            cursor.close();
        db.close();
        }
```

Is this right way to update retrieved query in service.Can someone help me.Thanks .

Comment: what is the problem? Are you getting an error or seeing something different than what was expected?

Comment: The problem is when i logout at that time i deleted the db file from android application package and all services will be stopped. But after logout db file deleted successfully , but getting error of SQLiteReadOnlyDatabaseException: attempt to write a readonly database . And above method of Loaddata() is in my service. And error will be at this line =  db.execSQL("update ActivityObjectList set DownLoad_Status='1' where imageaudioPath ='" + imageName + "'");}

Comment: It is not the best way to connect db. You should do it in your db helper class. Can you show your myDBHelper class as well?

Comment: A huge code in myDBHelper class. How can i show you .Can i discuss on chat